# Why wont the facebook stream.share popup work in Safari?

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been trying to tackle this since last week and for the life of me I cannot seem to get this working on safari, all other browsers render the popup except Safari.

It seems straight forward enough, load up the `javascript-sdk` asynchronously, initiate it, and call `FB.ui` with method 'stream.publish'.  The thing is I know this code should work in safari cause the example here does http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/stream.share.

I'm using this P3P header which we use that fixes a problem with IE7:

```
Response.AddHeader("P3P", "CP=\"NON DSP COR DEVa PSAa IVAo CONo OUR IND UNI PUR NAV DEM LOC\", " + "policyref=\"http://sweepstakes.mars.com/w3c/p3p.xml\"");
```

I'm hoping someone could offer the magic tip that's gonna get this working.  Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function (){

            FB.init({ appId: '<%= Common.appID %>', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

            var publish = {
                method: 'stream.publish',
                message: 'test',
                display: 'dialog'
            };

            FB.ui(publish);
        };

        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this for a canvas (iframe) applications? Safari probably hasn't authenticated due to its strict cross domain rules for cookies inside iframes.

Answer (score 1):

After many tests and frustrations.  A colleague pointed out that 'feed' is the new way of doing 'stream.publish'.  This fixed the issue.

Edit: Outdated answer.